# Issue implementing sample line chart from Chartis.js using GWT JSNI native method

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I'm currently trying to recreate a sample line chart code from Chartist.js using the below Javascript code and convert to GWT JSNI native method. When I tried executing the JSNI method, the output returns unexpected result as shown in first screen shot. However when i tried to execute the Javascript code in IE's developer console, it produces the right output as shown in the last screen.

What went wrong with JSNI GWT method code below? Thanks.

**Javascript code**

```
var data = {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
    series: [[5, 2, 4, 2, 0]]};

var options = {
    width: '300px',
     height: '200px'
};

new Chartist.Line('#chartTest', data, options);
```

**JSNI GWT method**

```
public native void createChart() /*-{
        var data = {
        labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
        series: [[5, 2, 4, 2, 0]]};
        var options = {
          width: "300px",
          height: "200px"
        };
        new $wnd.Chartist.Line("#chartTest", $wnd.data, $wnd.options);
    }-*/;
```

[JSNI GWT Native method output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42JrJ.jpg)

[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vgni.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many `$wnd`s in your code. Only put them where you are referencing some global object, not for local variables. When you construct the new `Line`, (in the namespace `Chartist` which is global), you need the `$wnd` prefix for `Chartist` but not for your local variables `data` and `options`:

```
public native void createChart() /*-{
    var data = {
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
    series: [[5, 2, 4, 2, 0]]};
    var options = {
      width: "300px",
      height: "200px"
    };
    new $wnd.Chartist.Line("#chartTest", data, options);
}-*/;
```

Edit: Okay, I think I figured it out. There is a "bug" in Chartist that prevents it from understanding your data (https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/blob/master/dist/chartist.js#L460):

```
} else if(value instanceof Array) {
```

This line of JS checks if your series values is an array, but not in the way you think - unlike Java, it doesn't check to see if the reference points to an array, but if the *constructor that creates* that object is the same object as `Array` is - and in your case, they are not the same - arrays are not always Arrays. In GWT, this is specifically because all GWT code is run in an iframe to avoid accidentally interfering with the page's own JS.

The library should be checking with `Array.isArray(value)`, but in lieu of that, you can change how you create the array to use the expected constructor for the main page, via `Array.from`, `Array.of`, or `new Array`. Here's a quick example of doing it with `Array.of`:

```
public native void createChart() /*-{
    var data = {
      labels: Array.of("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"),
      series: Array.of(Array.of(5, 2, 4, 2, 0))
    };
    var options = {
      width: "300px",
      height: "200px"
    };
    new $wnd.Chartist.Line("#chartTest", data, options);
}-*/;
```

It is possible that the same sort of problem will happen in the literal object creation too, but I'd need a full working sample or more error messages to verify this...

Comment: I tried before without adding $wnd. for both data and options but when this method is executed I got a JavaScript error "object doesnt support property or method 'map'". Btw I'm running using IE11

Comment: Hmm, hard to say then - my best guess without being able to see the code is that Chartist is monkeying with the native types and is changing how Object or Array work in the root window, and not the iframe where GWT runs. Let me see if I can learn a bit more and offer another suggestion to work around this broken behavior...

Comment: Nothing _looks_ wrong in what they are doing - do you have the full error and stack trace to share? Only other thing I can suggest is starting from `new $wnd.Object` and `new $wnd.Array`, but that seems unlikely to help...

Comment: This is the stack trace error i got from IE console: **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'map' File: chartist.min.js, Line: 994, Column: 21**

Comment: In chartist.min.js, the error indicated by the stack trace is executing the line of code below

Comment: function e(a, b, d, e, f) {
                var g = e["axis" + this.units.pos.toUpperCase()],
                   **h = this.ticks.map(this.projectValue.bind(this)),**
                    i = this.ticks.map(g.labelInterpolationFnc);

Comment: What version of IE are we talking about?  IE has supported Array.map since V9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I would try `myArray = new $wnd.Array(1, 2, 3, 4)` instead of Array.of.

Comment: Thanks for the update Colin. So it was a bug in Chartist in reading JS Arrays. I tried using the conventional array approach in Chart JS and it works perfectly fine. Going to stick to Chart JS for now

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
private static native void run (Element element) /*-{
var data = {
    labels : $wnd.Array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"),
    series : $wnd.Array($wnd.Array(5, 2, 4, 2, 0))
};
var options = {
    width : "300px",
    height : "200px"
};
new $wnd.Chartist.Line(element, data, options);
}-*/;
```

Edit:
this will also work

```
var data = $wnd.JSON.parse('{"labels" : ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],"series" : [[5, 2, 4, 2, 0]]}');
```

where as this does not

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"labels" : ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],"series" : [[5, 2, 4, 2, 0]]}');
```